# Dream Vestige attack bonus

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, attack

Dream Vestige, a monster from Libris Mortis,  has a Tendril attack:

> Attack: Tendril +15 melee touch

In my understanding the attack bonus consists of:

- +8 base attack bonus
- +5 dexterity modifier
- -2 size modifier
- +2 profane bonus from Desecrating Aura

to a total of +13, but the attack entry lists +15.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no source of attack bonus you haven’t accounted for; you aren’t missing anything. The statblock is wrong, which is unfortunately very common in 3.5e. Likely the authors forgot to include the −2 size penalty, but the dream vestige absolutely should have that penalty.